# On proving that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ is continuous in the topological sense (Adams and Franzosa)

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation

Please do not use any material related to metrics; these are not yet defined at this point in the text.

Assume I am working with the standard topology in all cases.

Let $(a, b) \subset \mathbb{R}$. I wish to show that the preimage induced by $f$ is open; i.e.,
$$f^{-1}((a, b)) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid a < xy < b\}\text{.}$$

This is from Example 4.6 of Adams and Franzosa:

> We can prove this explicity by showing that for each point $(p, q) \in f^{-1}((a, b))$, there is an open square centered at $(p, q)$ and contained in $f^{-1}((a, b))$. In fact, if we set $m = \min\{b - pq, pq - a\}$ and choose $\delta > 0$ so that $\delta|p|$, $\delta|q|$, and $3 \delta^2$ are all less than $m/3$, then it can be shown that $(p - \delta, p + \delta) \times (q - \delta, q + \delta) \subset f^{-1}((a, b))$.

Could someone please explain how one yields such a solution?

It is clear that $m$ represents the minimum vertical distance (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) between a point in $f^{-1}((a, b))$ and the two lines which bound the region, but I have no idea how the $\delta$ is chosen.

Comment: In such arguments the writer "chooses $\delta$" by reasoning backwards from the picture showing what inequality is needed. That inductive reasoning here is concealed by the phrase "it can be shown ...".

Comment: Draw a picture and note that if $(p',q')\in (p - \delta, p + \delta) \times (q - \delta, q + \delta)$, then $|p'q'-ab|\le |p'q'-aq'|+|aq'-q'b|+|q'b-ab|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the point in giving a proof like that when an extra line or two demonstrates the point clearly. It is not like space is at a premium in a 500+ page book!

We want to show that for the given $\delta$, if $x \in B(p,\delta)$ and $y \in B(q,\delta)$ then $xy \in (a,b)$. (Note that such $y$ satisfy $|y| < |q|+\delta$.)

Note that $m=\min(|a-pq|,|b-pq|)$, so it is sufficient to show that
$|xy-pq| < m$, since then $xy \in B(pq, m) \subset (a,b)$.

\begin{eqnarray}
|xy-pq| &\le& |xy-py|+|py-pq| \\
&\le& |y||x-p| + |p||y-q| \\
&\le& (|q|+\delta) \delta+ |p| \delta \\
&=& |q|  \delta + \delta^2 + |p| \delta \\
&\le& {m \over 3} + {1 \over 3} {m \over 3} + {m \over 3} \\
&<& m
\end{eqnarray}